# How to display multiple pins on a google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display multiple pins on a google map but it shows only one pin. I am using this code

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html

But it displays a pin only on the first location.

How do you display multiple pins?

Here is what I have so far:

```
  public class EventMap extends MapActivity {

MyLocationOverlay me = null;

Vector<OverlayItem> overlay;

List<Overlay> mOverlay;
private Drawable drawable1;
MapOverlay itemizedoverlay;
private MapView mapView;

private OverlayItem [] accessItem = {
            new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(35953700,-83926158), "Access Title 1", "Access snippet 1"),
            new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(35954000,-83928200), "Access Title 2", "Access snippet 2"),
            new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(35955000,-83927558), "Access Title 3", "Access snippet 3"),
            new OverlayItem( new GeoPoint(35954000,-83927158), "Access Title 4", "Access snippet 4") 
        };


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.event_map);
    MapController mMapController;
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapView.setTraffic(false);
    mMapController = mapView.getController();
    GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint(35954200,-83929200); 
    mMapController.animateTo(gp);
    mMapController.setZoom(5);
    setOverlay();
    //mapView.invalidate();

   }


public void setOverlay()
{
    mOverlay = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable1 = getParent().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin);
    itemizedoverlay = new MapOverlay(drawable1);
    for(int i=0; i<accessItem.length;i++)
    {
        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(accessItem[i]);
    }
    mOverlay.add(itemizedoverlay);

}


    public class MapOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

        Context ctx;

         private ArrayList<OverlayItem> items;

        public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
            populate();

        }

        public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx) {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
            this.ctx = ctx;
            items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
            populate();

        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {

            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {

            return items.size();
        }
         public void removeItem(int i){
                items.remove(i);
                populate();
            }

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int index) {
             Toast.makeText(getParent(),items.get(index).getSnippet(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             return true;
        }

        public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
            items.add(overlay);
            populate();
        }


   }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a simpler sample app that shows multiple `OverlayItems` in an `ItemizedOverlay`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk

Comment: @CommonsWare I also try this link but shows only one pin

Comment: Then your development machine is broken. I guarantee you that my sample app works. It has worked for over three years. In fact, for grins, I just tested it now, and it still works. It shows four markers at four locations in New York City. Simply download the sample, put your Maps API key into the `main.xml` layout file, and it works.

Comment: @commonsWare I give you my code can you tell me what is problem

Comment: Newts, use the code commonware posted. That surely works.